# Invalid syntax error in my Python code

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.7

I keep getting an "invalid syntax" notification around `room105`

```
*room15 = room("Check out the lab")

room15.setDescription("You look around the lab. You find nothing of importance, really."

room105 = room("Continue to look around")

room105.setDescription("You still don't find anything.")

room16 = room("Go back up trapdoor and into the sweet room")

room16.setDescription("You go up the ladder and into the room, only to find... The leader! He becomes startled, and begins to come at you!")


room106 = room("Talk to him")

room106.setDescription("you attempt to speak with the leader, but he comes at you too fast, and kills you.                                                                              GAME OVER.")

room106.setFunction(lambda: lockroom (room16))*
```

I'm trying to make a text adventure. When I tested it before, it worked perfectly, now, as soon as I put in the `room105` bit, I'm getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: When you have problems like this, please post complete tracebacks.

Comment: Also, when you get a `SyntaxError` on a line that looks perfectly fine, look at the line above it—if you have unclosed parens, brackets, braces, quotes, or a stray backslash, etc., Python thinks that line is a perfectly good partial statement, and this line is an invalid rest-of-that-statement.

Comment: You will have the same problem at room106.

Comment: @dansalmo No he won't, but only because there's a huge amount of very misleading whitespace in the middle of his string.

Comment: I wish the edit windows would wrap. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 6):

```
*room15 = room("Check out the lab")

room15.setDescription("You look around the lab. You find nothing of importance, really."

room105 = room("Continue to look around")
```

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the second line.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an asterisk before your variable name at the very beginning as well as at the very end, which is illegal but probably just a typo (but please proofread your questions before posting them!)

Your **actual** problem is that you're missing the closing parentheses after `room15.setDescription(...`

Comment: That first one wouldn't give `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, but `SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple`. (IIRC, the wording is different in 2.7.4 vs. 3.3.1… and earlier 2.7 may not have had the distinction and just said `invalid syntax`… so, maybe not.)

Comment: Thank you all so much. I'm an idiot. I guess i'm just blind. thank you all so much for your time. i really really appreciate it. (if it's not obvious, i'm a bit of a n00b at this stuff.)

Comment: @abarnert Just for the record, 2.7.4 and 2.6.6 both give `Syntax Error: invalid syntax` for the asterisk problem. It seems that specifying the specific syntax error (at least in this case) begins in Python 3. Interestingly, the asterisk at the *end* produces the boilerplate `invalid syntax` error up until at least Python 3.2.2.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: Now that I think of it, that makes sense. In 3.3, `*a = foo` could easily be a mistaken attempt at something like `a, *b = foo`, which is what the error description is telling you. But in 2.7, `a, *b = foo` is still a `SyntaxError`.